# Updating a PHP text-based game continuously

Tags: php

I'm building a multiplayer game in PHP. Each game is split into stages that last a set amount of time - currently 2 minutes. In each stage, players work together for a set amount of time until the game either advances to the next stage, or the stage (and hence the game) is lost, and a new game starts again.

I have a vision of playing the game on an HTML page, where users can see how much time is left in the current stage through a constantly updating countdown clock.  When the countdown clock reaches zero, the game either advances or ends, and the result is returned through Ajax. What I'm having problems with is the (theoretical) thought of 100 players playing the game simultaneously.

How do I call the update script? If I call it by running PHP, which player's browser calls it? If a player's browser refreshes the content one second before the stage actually finishes, what happens?

Is PHP the right language for a game like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is PHP the right language for a game like this?"
Yes, if you do it right.  Here's how you do it...

Using a method called Comet, you can have multiple clients pulling data from the server, but only when that data is updated.  It works something like this:

1. Client A makes pull request to server.
2. Server waits, keeping connection to Client A open.
3. Client B makes pull request to server.
4. Server waits, keeping connection to Client B open.
5. Client A pushes new data to server.
6. Server pushes new data to Client A and Client B through still open connections.
7. Client A makes pull request...
8. etc...

In other words, it means that all clients receive up-to-date information immediately it is pushed to the server by any client.  This means you don't have to implement a "refresh every x seconds" system, which is good for 2 reasons:

1) You don;t waste time and bandwidth make requests to the server when nothing has happened;
2) All the clients get data pushed to them at the same time, that's absolutely up-to-date and not x seconds old.

In practice, Comet is implemented via AJAX. Google for some examples of Comet- it's pretty simple, and extremely useful.

Comment: Thanks. However, let's say Client A doesn't push new data to the server, but after 2 minutes the code is programmed to change something without user input. If nobody calls the script, how can the script send data?

Comment: The script is "called" when the client makes a request to the server.  The server keeps the connection open and only responds when there's new data to push- it doesn't matter how that data got to the server in the first place (whether from another client or generated by the server itself).  Once the client receives the new data, it immediately makes a new request to the server, which stays open until more new data is pushed, and so on.

Comment: Is the solution quite rudimentary then - having a kind of admin client that just continuously calls the script?

Comment: No, it's not rudimentary.  The whole point of Comet is that data is ONLY transferred when the data on the server actually changes, which is after all the minimum number of transfers possible.  Whilst the client does "continuously call the script", it can only do so AFTER something has changed, as the server only responds to the request when it is ready to do so.  Only when the server responds (i.e. when there is new data) can the client make a new request.  Compare this to simply polling the server every x seconds, where 99% of the time there could be nothing new to pull from the server.

Answer (score 1):

In client-server games, your server should be running a simulation in parallel to the client's simulation (the game).

Usually the server simulation is authoritative, so that when, say, a match is over it will inform all clients in the match that the simulation state changed to "match over" or whatever.   The client will then lock the UI or present a "Game Over" message or announce winners-- whatever you want.

So for you, your server should run the count down timer, while the clients keeping polling (via AJAX or WebSockets) the server for state changes.  When the server's timer hits zero, the next time clients poll the server, the server will say, "Hey, yo-- the game's over!".

**Edit**

I'd also like to say that PHP will probably work, but you have to understand that PHP was built for web services, not games.  Simple games like tic tac toe or checkers or chess can become quite complex when you toss in multiplayer functionality.  Simulations often require threading.  PHP can do threading but it can get very ugly if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: I would recommend looking into websockets for this form of communication. I know IE doesn't support it yet but its a lot faster than AJAX.

Comment: +1 for Dpolehonski, modern in-browser browser games mostly all uses websockets, it's a real connection and will fallback on ajax polling if the browser doesn't support it, depending on the library you chose.

Comment: Didn't even think of websockets.  Added it to my answer.  Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are using the PHP session system, the script will recognize the Ajax request as being from the same user who (for example) logged in into your game.

One second before the stage finishes, well you could return in PHP the time left to the stage so the javascript counter stay synchronized? Both the server and the clients must be aware of the status of the game, else expect hackers somewhen.